# Aligned TOC with titletoc

Tags: hyperref, calculations, titletoc, alignment

I'm trying to get my toc build with the titletoc package as I'm using it to do other content tables with it. I get it to work almost like i want it to, but i have some issues:
[image]

First of all i have do calculate the intentation manually as shown below.

```
\settowidth{\tocindent}{2.12.2}% calculation of the indentation
```

I tried different approaches of trying to calculate the maximum width by redefining the `\subsubsection` command but that didn't work for me. I would love to have LaTeX calculate this value for me instead of typing it in.

The second problem I have are my unnumbered sections, they are supposed to align with the numbers. I got it to work with the paragraph definition, but that just makes so much headaches concerning the hyperref package:

- `Difference (3) between bookmark levels is greater (hyperref) than one, level fixed`
- `The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not(hyperref) be the same. Added a new anchor`

Following the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\tocindent}

%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\settowidth{\tocindent}{2.12.2}% calculation of the indentation
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\titlecontents{section}[\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr  \tocindent+0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}[0pt]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{0pt}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\startcontents[sections]
{\Large Inhaltsverzeichnis}\\
\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection B 1}
\subsection{Subsection B 2}
\subsection{Subsection B 3}
\subsection{Subsection B 4}
\subsection{Subsection B 5}
\subsection{Subsection B 6}
\subsection{Subsection B 7}
\subsection{Subsection B 8}
\subsection{Subsection B 9}
\subsection{Subsection B 10}
\subsection{Subsection B 11}
\subsection{Subsection B 12}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.2}
\subsection{Subsection B 14}
\subsection{Subsection B 15}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection C 1}
\subsection{Subsection C 2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection C 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures (section)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{List of Figures (paragraph)}
\end{document}
```

Hope you guys can help me out!

---

**EDIT**

with the help of [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) i've come so far thet the width is now calculated by using the `eqmakebox` in the labeldefinition:

```
\documentclass[10pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newlength{\tocindent}
\setlength{\tocindent}{0.8em}% calculation of the indentation

\titlecontents{section}[\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent}}
{\hspace*{-\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent}}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{TOC}+\tocindent}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\renewcommand\thesection{\eqmakebox[TOC][l]{\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\eqmakebox[TOC][l]{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\eqmakebox[TOC][l]{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}

\begin{document}
\startcontents[sections]
{\Large Inhaltsverzeichnis}\\
\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section*{Section B*}
\subsection{Subsection B 1}
\subsection{Subsection B 2}
\subsection{Subsection B 3}
\subsection{Subsection B 4}
\subsection{Subsection B 5}
\subsection{Subsection B 6}
\subsection{Subsection B 7}
\subsection{Subsection B 8}
\subsection{Subsection B 9}
\subsection{Subsection B 10}
\subsection{Subsection B 11}
\subsection{Subsection B 12}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.2}
\subsection{Subsection B 14}
\subsection{Subsection B 15}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection C 1}
\subsection{Subsection C 2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection C 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures (section)}
\end{document}
```

It works but also the sectiontitles and subsectiontitles get pushed away in the normal text.

[image]

left according to the above code with the `\eqmakebox`, right without the `\eqmakebox` how i would like it to look like.

I also tried setting the width by using `\eqsetminwidthto{TOC}{\arabic{section}}` in the labeldefinition but that just results in errors.
Ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I suppose that you actually don't want to have paragraphs in your table of of contents?

Comment: that's right, it is just a workaround I implemented to get the numberless entries without the indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i managed to fix my problem myself. (yay good for me)

I actually defined the `\eqmakebox` for each sectiongroup and added them to a total indentation for the TOC. Therefore each Label only has a box around the corresponding number:

- **1** Section 1
- 1.**1** Section 1.1
- 1.23.**13** Section 1.23.13

And it does not affect the sections in the Text.

```
\documentclass[10pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{titletoc, titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newlength{\tocindent}
\setlength{\tocindent}{0.2em}% additional indentation

\titlecontents{section}[%
    \dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{%
    \dimexpr
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\hspace*{%
    -\dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[%
    \dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{%
    \dimexpr
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\hspace*{%
    -\dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[%
    \dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{%
    \dimexpr
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\hspace*{%
    -\dimexpr 
    \eqboxwidth{TOCS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSS}+
    \eqboxwidth{TOCSSS}+\tocindent}}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\renewcommand\thesection{\eqmakebox[TOCS][l]{\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\eqmakebox[TOCSS][l]{\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\eqmakebox[TOCSSS][l]{\arabic{subsubsection}}}

\begin{document}
\startcontents[sections]
{\Large Inhaltsverzeichnis}\\
\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection B 1}
\setcounter{subsection}{12}
\subsection{Subsection B 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.2}
\subsection{Subsection B 14}
\subsection{Subsection B 15}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection C 1}
\subsection{Subsection C 2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.1}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{12}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection C 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures (section)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the argument of `titlecontents` devoted to unnumbered section (which you've left blank).

Unrelated: you should load `hyperref` as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notably, `cleveref` should be loaded *aafter* `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass[10pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newlength{\tocindent}

%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\settowidth{\tocindent}{2.12.2}% calculation of the indentation
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\titlecontents{section}[\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em}}
{\hspace*{-\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em}}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{\dimexpr \tocindent+0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\startcontents[sections]
{\Large Inhaltsverzeichnis}\\
\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection B 1}
\subsection{Subsection B 2}
\subsection{Subsection B 3}
\subsection{Subsection B 4}
\subsection{Subsection B 5}
\subsection{Subsection B 6}
\subsection{Subsection B 7}
\subsection{Subsection B 8}
\subsection{Subsection B 9}
\subsection{Subsection B 10}
\subsection{Subsection B 11}
\subsection{Subsection B 12}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B 13.2}
\subsection{Subsection B 14}
\subsection{Subsection B 15}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection C 1}
\subsection{Subsection C 2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection C 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection C 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures (section)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solves one Problem :)
Any idea if the automated calculation of the witdh `\tocindent` might be possible?

Comment: Maybe inserting the subsubsection labels in an `\eqmakebox` command, and using the`\eqboxwidth` command? Take a look at the `eqparbox` package documentation.